# php receive and use xml posted data from external website

Tags: php, xml

Im having hard time on receiving xml data that is send to my url from other/external website. External website suppose to send some xml format data to my url and I need to receive it and use data on it.

I have tried:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("https://example.com");
```

and

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('https://example.com');
```

I found these in web and tried it but got no success. Do anyone has idea on this since I am new in xml.
Also is there is any way I could confirm if data has come to my url or not?

External website sends data like:

```
<Message date="25/04/2018 13:26:33">
<Version>1.0</Version>
<OrderID>4232434</OrderID>
</Message>
```

Comment: If you are passed the data - use simplexml_load_string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Comment: i have used that too and it return empty data

Comment: OK - so can you show your code which shows how you get the data (is it `$_POST`) and how you try and access the data.  Also show what you mean by 'empty data' as using `print_r()` isn't the right way to check XML (but we don't know a we can't see what your doing)

Comment: can you tell me the right way to print out XML script that is received from another url.

Comment: If it's SimpleXML - use `asXML()` - http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Comment: If you added some code, then a proper answer could be given, but at the moment it's just ideas.

Comment: its a simple xml and i have used asXML() too like
     echo "<p>".htmlentities ($xmlData->asXML())."</p>";

Comment: Without code, it's impossible to help much more.

Comment: ok, another website sends data like:
<Message date="25/04/2018 13:26:33"><Version>1.0</Version><OrderID>34523</OrderID>
</Message>
I have url from where this data is sent. now i want to receive this data.

Comment: this is how i tried.
$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents('<url>'));
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);
echo "<p>".htmlentities ($xmlData->asXML())."</p>";
exit();

Comment: I have also added it in post

Answer (score -1):

If the data is POSTed to you then your PHP file should have

```
if(isset($_POST['xml'])){
//do domething
}
```

Comment: it was posted to my url as XML format. So, it does not work like this